# Gmail email parsing with python when there are unicode characters in body

Tags: python, email, unicode

I have written a script to parse an email. It works fine when receiving letters from Mac OS X Mail client (just this one tested so far), but my parser failes when letters contain unicode letters in their body part.

For example, I have sent a message with content `ąčę`.

And here is my part of script which parses body and attachments at the same time:

```
p = FeedParser()
p.feed(msg)
msg = p.close()
attachments = []
body = None
for part in msg.walk():
  if part.get_content_type().startswith('multipart/'):
    continue
  try:
    filename = part.get_filename()
  except:
    # unicode letters in filename, set default name then
    filename = 'Mail attachment'

  if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain" and not body:
    body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
  elif filename is not None:
    content_type = part.get_content_type()
    attachments.append(ContentFile(part.get_payload(decode=True), filename))

if body is None:
    body = ''
```

Well, I mentioned that it works with letters from OS X Mail, but with Gmail letters it doesn't.

The traceback:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 116, in get_response
>     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
>     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
>     return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/PycharmProjects/rezervavau/bms/messages/views.py", line 66, in accept
>     Message.accept(request.POST.get('msg'))
>   File "/Users/aemdy/PycharmProjects/rezervavau/bms/messages/models.py", line 261, in accept
>     thread=thread
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 149, in create
>     return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 391, in create
>     obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 532, in save
>     force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 627, in save_base
>     result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
>     return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1633, in insert_query
>     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 920, in execute_sql
>     cursor.execute(sql, params)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 47, in execute
>     sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/operations.py", line 201, in last_executed_query
>     return cursor.query.decode('utf-8')
>   File "/Users/aemdy/virtualenvs/django1.5/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 115: invalid continuation byte

My script gives me the following body `����`. How can I decode it to get `ąčę` back?

Comment: The string with the special characters that you are sending is latin-1 encoded and you're trying to interpret it as being utf-8, which obviously fails.

Comment: But I need a universal way to parse the body of the email message. How can I achieve that? Decoding latin-1 results in `àèæë`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I found a solution myself. I will do some testing now and will let you guys now if anything fails.

I needed to decode the body again:

```
body = part.get_payload(decode=True).decode(part.get_content_charset())
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using this:

```
from email.Iterators import typed_subpart_iterator


def get_charset(message, default="ascii"):
    """Get the message charset"""

    if message.get_content_charset():
        return message.get_content_charset()

    if message.get_charset():
        return message.get_charset()

    return default

def get_body(message):
    """Get the body of the email message"""

    if message.is_multipart():
        #get the plain text version only
        text_parts = [part
                      for part in typed_subpart_iterator(message,
                                                         'text',
                                                         'plain')]
        body = []
        for part in text_parts:
            charset = get_charset(part, get_charset(message))
            body.append(unicode(part.get_payload(decode=True),
                                charset,
                                "replace"))

        return u"\n".join(body).strip()

    else: # if it is not multipart, the payload will be a string
          # representing the message body
        body = unicode(message.get_payload(decode=True),
                       get_charset(message),
                       "replace")
        return body.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [`email.iterators`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.iterators.html) (not sure it will solve your encoding problems though).

Comment: Well, I don't think that I can find the solution there. It iterates correctly, but decoding/encoding fails hard.

Comment: Could you add the email you're using to test to your question then ? It's difficult to reproduce the problem otherwise.